# « S’entendre », « viser », « se dire » ou autre?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, oral, reformulation

Mon programme de la semaine est très chargé et toi tu es en vacances la semaine prochaine. Pour le cinéma, on pourrait

…s’entendre sur le 10 janvier.

…viser le 10 janvier.

…se dire le/au 10 janvier.

…se donner rendez-vous le 10 janvier.

Autre tournure plus idiomatique que vous diriez à l’oral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« S'entendre » ne convient pas vraiment.

> (TLFi) α) **Se mettre d'accord avec quelqu'un**
> − […]
> − **en nouant une entente momentanée avec quelqu'un**

Il y a l'idée fondamentale de se mettre d'accord dans ce verbe, mais en plus c'est un terme qui implique des notions plus importantes que celles de décider du moment d'un rendez-vous ou d'une rencontre.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entente)) **entente**  b) Fait de se mettre d'accord sur un point particulier, accord temporaire ou durable fondé sur une communauté de principes ou d'intérêts.

« Viser » me parait être du vocabulaire farfelu moderne et je ne l'emploierais pas. « Se dire »  ne semble pas très judicieux, ça semble refléter une façon très personnelle de s'exprimer.

Il y a l'expression verbale simple « se mettre d'accord sur », qui ira très bien à mon avis. Assez formel, le verbe « convenir » est aussi une option.

« Se donner rendez-vous » est aussi convenable. Il y a cependant d'autres façons plus ou moins familières.

- Mon programme de la semaine est très chargé et toi tu es en vacances la semaine prochaine. Pour le cinéma, on pourrait

…se mettre d'accord  sur le 10 janvier.

…se donner rendez-vous le 10 janvier.

…convenir du 10 janvier.

- Mon programme de la semaine est très chargé et toi tu es en vacances la semaine prochaine. Pour le cinéma,

…qu'est-ce que tu dirais du 10 janvier ?

…j'ai pensé au 10 janvier.

…il me semble que le 10 janvier conviendrait, qu'est-ce que tu en dis ?

…peut-être que le 10 janvier t'irait ?

…qu'est-ce que tu penses du 10 janvier ?

…qu'est-ce que tu dirais du 10 janvier ?

…le 10 janvier t'irait ?

…pourquoi ne pas y aller le 10 janvier ?

…allons y le 10 janvier. (*intonation de la suggestion*)

…le 10 janvier me convient, et toi ?

Answer (score 0):

À l'oral je suis très flexible, ce qui fait que j'accepte toutes tes formulations sans exception et salue la spontanéité de ton réflexe linguistique :

…*s’entendre*<sup>1</sup> sur le 10 janvier.
…*viser* le 10 janvier.
…*(se) dire* le/au 10 janvier.
…*se donner rendez-vous* le 10 janvier.

J'ajouterais, tel qu'évoqué dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52025) (mais ici sans remanier) :

…[*penser*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/penser) au 10 janvier. [je ne sais pas si c'est *estimer, avoir à l'esprit, prévoir, former un dessein/avoir l'intention*, mais j'accepte.]

Et encore :

…[***s'enligner***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/enligner) pour le 10 janvier [QC, familier, très usuel]
…[*se fixer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixer) comme date le 10 janvier. [déterminer]
…[*arranger/planifier/organiser*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/arranger) ça pour le 10 janvier.
…*y aller pour* le 10 janvier. [choisir, possiblement similaire à la tournure [*va pour*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/aller_1#dc44d1d26362f8d6) + nom]

Et plus généralement, comme on a déjà le conditionnel (*on pourrait*) évoquant la possibilité, directement proposer d' :

…*y aller* le 10 janvier.
— D'accord !

Et on n'a pas besoin de verbe pour nommer l'action de proposer etc. quand on le déduit de l'acceptation.

---

<sub>Avec le verbe [*entendre*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/entendre#contenu_macro_sens-645-6), si l'on peut s'entendre sur les clauses d'un contrat ou [sur la façon d'agir](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=s%27entendre&i=&lettr=indx_catlog_c&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) on peut certainement s'entendre sur une date pour aller au cinéma, et j'accepte la réduction que tu proposes et même avec la préposition *pour* (*...le 10 janvier*) ; je n'ai jamais entendu parler d'un verbe qui refuserait de s'appliquer aux propos d'un locuteur parce qu'ils manqueraient d'importance et je rejette d'emblée cette notion.</sub>